# Unsure how to correctly use Django models for a relationship with extra info

Tags: django, django-models

I have clients and contacts, and each client can have any number of contacts and each contact can have any number of types. For example, client 1 can have two billing contacts, person A and person B, and two business contacts, person B and person C.
I know it would be possible to model this with the following models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id #primary key
    #other data

class Contact(models.Model):
    id #primary key
    #other data

class Relationship(models.Model):
    client_id=ForeignKey(Client)
    contact_id=ForeignKey(Contact)
    type=CharField(max_length=255)#or some other field that represents the type
```

but this seems incorrect to me because the Relationship model does not represent an object but a relation between other objects. Do I need to do it this way, or is there some way of making the models so that every one actually represents the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but this seems incorrect to me because the Relationship model does not represent an object but a relation between other objects.

A relationship is a first-class thing.

In a simple RDBMS models, the relationship was implied by a shared key (FK in one, PK in another)

However, when you have many-to-many association tables, you create an explicit row which embodies the relationship.

You're just enriching the association object with additional attributes.

This is fine.  It's common, in fact.

It's a generalization of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Also, read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks. I saw that and I did not even realize that was what I was looking for.